# Decode Azure Blob SAS Url correctly to avoid Signature not well formed error

Tags: c#, azure, neo4j, azure-blob-storage

For further processing in Neo4j I need the SAS encoded URL unescaped because Neo4j do the encoding again and leads to a 403 http error code.

Code to upload a json file to Azure Blob Storage and get the encoded SAS Url and decode it with `DecodeUrlString`:

```
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(absConnectionString, absContainerName);
await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

string fileName = fileKey + ".json";

// Get a reference to a blob
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

await using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
{
    response = await blobClient.UploadAsync(ms, new BlobUploadOptions
    {
        HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders
        {
            ContentType = "application/json",
            ContentEncoding = "UTF-8"
        }
    });
}

var absoluteUrl = string.Empty;
if (response.GetRawResponse().Status == 201)
{
    // 1 hour valid
    var originalUrl = blobClient.GenerateSasUri(BlobSasPermissions.Read, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1)).AbsoluteUri;
    originalUrl = DecodeUrlString(originalUrl);
}


private static string DecodeUrlString(string url)
    {
        string newUrl;
        while ((newUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(url)) != url)
            url = newUrl;
        
        return newUrl;
    }
```

Sometimes the decoded URL will work and sometimes I got this error (depends on the SAS encoded URL, and especially the Signature field => starts with &sig=) with Neo4j and in Browser:

> `AuthenticationFailed` Server failed to
> authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
> is formed correctly including the signature.
> RequestId:552242c2-301e-003e-55d9-457612000000
> Time:2022-04-01T15:04:20.4824344Z
> Signature fields not well
> formed.

Original Blob URL:

```
https://[ACCOUNTNAME].blob.core.windows.net/[CONTAINER]/file.json?sv=2021-04-10&se=2022-04-01T10%3A10%3A46Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=%2BTCB%2FwyaV5RfI7X7%2Fb7yoOlGZSzd5OjgXw2GDOCkB04%3D
```

Decoded URL:

```
https://[ACCOUNTNAME].blob.core.windows.net/[CONTAINER]/file.json?sv=2021-04-10&se=2022-04-01T10:10:46Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=+TCB/wyaV5RfI7X7/b7yoOlGZSzd5OjgXw2GDOCkB04=
```

The problem with Neo4j is described here: [apoc.load.jsonParams with Azure Blob signed URL leads to http 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71692679/apoc-load-jsonparams-with-azure-blob-signed-url-leads-to-http-403-error)

How can I unescape the SAS URL correctly to avoid this kind of errors?

Comment: Can you share a SAS URL which gave you the error?

Comment: Also please clarify what neo4j is doing and how you’re storing the URI. It’s not clear how neo4j can alter your text.

Comment: @GauravMantri is added now.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have added a link to the problem with Neo4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved now with the Neo4j v4.4.7 and apoc v4.4.0.5 release.